# Matlab script cannot produce and save a job artifact when ran from pipeline

Tags: powershell, matlab, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running a simple job that aims to:

1. create a file,
2. write a random string into it,
3. and save it in the project directory (`CI_PROJECT_DIR`) as a job artifact.

I am doing this by running two kinds of commands in `powershell` from the pipeline:

1. :

   ```
   echo "test 1" >> ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\output_1.txt
   ```
2. :

   ```
   matlab -r "f = fopen(sprintf('%s\\output_2.txt', pwd),'w'); fprintf(f,'%d', 'test 2'); fclose(f); exit;"
   ```

Command (1) is using a regular `powershell` command, whereas command (2) is using a `Matlab` script.

My current issue is as follows: command (1) creates/writes/saves the file, whereas command (2) does not.

Here is the job output to the upload of artifacts:

```
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=11596 revision=c6bb62f6 version=14.10.0
C:\GitLab-Runner\my\path\output_1.txt: found 1 matching files and directories 
WARNING: C:\GitLab-Runner\my\path\output_2.txt: no matching files
```

If I run the `Matlab` script manually (outside the pipeline) from `powershell` or `Matlab` itself, it runs smoothly and saves the file properly. But when I run it from the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file it does not. Why is that? Should I run things from the `MATLABROOT` or something similar? EDIT: I tried the last one and it did not work, I ran things from `MATLABROOT\R2021a\bin`.

I also tried using the `-batch` option instead or the `-r` option but the job fails to finish and gives the following error:

```
ERROR: MATLAB error Exit Status: 0x00000001
```

Could it be that the batch mode does not activate somehow in `Matlab` on my set up? I have `MATLAB 2021a`.

---

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:  
  - savefile

job1:
  stage: savefile
  tags:
    - my_runner
  script:
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - echo "test 1" >> ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\output_1.txt
    - matlab -r "f = fopen(sprintf('%s\\output_2.txt', pwd),'w'); fprintf(f,'%d', 'test 2'); fclose(f);"
    - ls
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\output_1.txt
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}\output_2.txt
```

Here the job output to the `ls` command:

```
$ ls
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                
-a----        27/04/2022     09:45            394 .gitlab-ci.yml                                                       
-a----        27/04/2022     09:45             18 output_1.txt                                                         
-a----        25/04/2022     19:11           6373 README.md
```

Comment: do you just need to create that output_2.txt file as a blank document before you run the matlab command? It looks like the first thing the matlab command is doing is trying to open the output_2.txt file - I'm not sure if it will automatically create it if its missing.

Comment: @Panomosh In Matlab `fopen` with the `w` option creates the file if it doesn't exist and overwrites it if it does. Same thing in Python. Like I said, when I run the script on its own in Matlab it works fine (creates/writes/saves the file). I tried creating the `output_2.txt` file before hand and it doesn't write into the file either.

Comment: Not exactly GitLab but according to this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/765851-why-do-jenkins-builds-with-matlab-fail-on-a-windows-machine), `ERROR: MATLAB error Exit Status: 0x00000001` might point to a "potential MATLAB licensing error." Is this something that you can verify on your runner?